# What is the meaning of "due within" in this passage?

Tags: meaning

> CME Clearing marks open contracts to market twice daily and settles
>   payment obligations once in the morning and once in the afternoon of
>   each business day. Morning settlement occurs at 08:30 ET and includes
>   options premiums passed from buyer to seller and initial and variation
>   margin (also known as initial and maintenance performance bonds,
>   respectively) deposits. CME Clearing sends payment instructions to
>   each settlement bank prior to the 08:30 ET deadline and requests a
>   confirmation of payment prior to the deadline. Afternoon settlement
>   includes maintenance performance bond deposits, which are **due within**
>   one hour of CME Clearing requesting payment from its clearing members.

Comment: Welcome! Did you check the dictionary? Can you explain why it was not helpful? Please see [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) and the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to add to your question. Tell us what your dictionary tells you about the English words _due_ and _within,_ and tell us what you did not understand when you consulted your dictionary. Tell us about any other research you have done about the phrase _due within._ Your question may be closed unless we have a little more information, and we would like to help you.

Answer (score 1):

> **due within** *time-range*

means something needs to be done **before** the expiration of the stated *time-range*.

In your example, it means all payments need to be processed within one hour of payment requests.  The automated speed in which financial transactions take place nowadays has led to something called **straight-through-processing** (**STP**) where an automated electronic pipeline is setup end-to-end.